# TypeScript - not updating javascript after 0.9 install

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

First I did not have intellisense when using typescript.
So I installed typescript 0.9 for vs2012.

Now I have intellisense but the javascript files no longer updates.

I have checked the typescript options "compile typescript on save".
Still, nothing compiles.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you updated your Web Esentials plugin to newest version.

Web Essentials no longer supports TypeScript compilation.
You have two options to fix your problem:

1. Revert back to earlier version of web essentials (2.7 or 2.6)
2. Update your project file to handle TypeScript compile

see: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

and http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

This may also be helpful: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/454045

Comment: Thanks. Rolling back to Typescript 2.9 helps me! Other approaches to fix that problem not work.